# How to verify FLAC files against the AccurateRip database?

Tags: audio, compact-disc, ripping, flac, accuraterip

I've been ripping my CD's to CUE+FLAC so that I get image files that allow me to replicate the actual CD. This serves me as a backup and as an easy access to the "media" if I need to re-rip the CD's (in case of an improvement in the AAC/MP3 encoder, or a new format).

Some CD's were ripped using EAC, others using XLD and more recently I've been using Rip. All of them support AccurateRip, but some of my CD's weren't found in the database and for others AccurateRip wasn't used at all.

I would like to verify the FLAC files against the AccurateRip database so that I can find if the CD appeared there, and if matches my ripped image. If it doesn't, I could try again at a later time or try re-ripping with a different tool and verify the AccurateRip hash against that of my first rip.

Is it possible to verify existing FLAC files against the AccurateRip database? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CueTools is supposed to be able to do that.

http://www.cuetools.net/doku.php/cuetools:download

.

Reference:

http://forum.dbpoweramp.com/showthread.php?t=17770

> Cuetools will now process batches of flac files and verify them again accurate rip. You no longer have to create the cue file.

.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I'm looking for! Do you know an equivalent tool for OS X?

Comment: See this...http://cuetools.darwinports.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same thing.  Seems to be a series of tools.  This one shows the most promise, though it doesn't seem to work off a single WAV/FLAC and a CUE file:

https://github.com/spadev/cdrip-tools

I've used it very briefly tonight and am pretty happy with it, in conjunction with this little gem from commandlinefu.com:

```
shnsplit -t "%n-%t" -f $CUEFILE $FLACFILE
~/cdrip-tools/arverify.py *.wav
```

Here's another -- I didn't try it as I didn't want to install Haskell

https://github.com/tensor5/flAccurateRip

Comment: For anyone else trying `arverify`: if the original disc had a pre-gap (hidden track one audio) then you may need to add sectors - try with `arverify -a 32`

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X users... [X Lossless Decoder (XLD)](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) is an open-source tool that can transcode audio from CDs and files.  It uses the [AccurateRip](http://www.accuraterip.com/) database to verify rips and will happily work with either CUE file or a folder of FLAC files.  Both options are available in the "Open" menu - and once a source is opened, it shows whether AccurateRip was used.  You can simply click the button in the bottom left-hand corner to generate the checksums and test against the database manually too.