# What does "differs in x samples" mean?

Tags: accuraterip

Of all albums I've ripped some tracks have a note "differs in x samples @00:00:00-00:00:00", for instance:

```
1   | (1276/1301) Accurately ripped, or (9/1301) differs in 5000 samples @01:23:31-01:23:05
```

From [CUETools wiki](http://cue.tools/wiki/CUETools_log):

> **Differs in ...**
>   Partial match this track, might be repairable

Does this simply indicate that the rip isn't accurate?

Answer (score 1):

The way that I read that is that 1276 out of 1301 rips match yours exactly, and there are a further 9 which have a slight difference to yours. The way I would interpret that is you and the 1276 others are very likely to have a good rip and the 9 other have a rip slightly less so.

I'd infer that your rip is accurate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have to research before I can accept the answer. Adding sources would help!

Comment: I found trying to understand the accuraterip output difficult because there is a lack of documentation for it. It's a while since I looked at this but I did ask a question on here about it to aid my understanding. Nobody answered so I [answered it myself](https://superuser.com/a/1225582) to detail my own understanding after my own research. I don't know if that helps at all but it's the best I was able to come up with.